How to pass a react component to a object property as value in TS
I have a routes.ts file. And I'm declaring my routes object as below -
type PublicRoute = {
    path: string,
    element: JSX.Element
}

const publicRoutes: Array<PublicRoute> = [
    {
        path: "/signup",
        element: <SignUp />
    }
]

But getting a compilation error as
Expected ">" but found "/"
  10 |      {
  11 |          path: "/signup",
  12 |          element: <SignUp /
     |                           ^
  13 |  ]

I want to use it through a .map function.

.ts files do not support the instanciation of JSX elements like this , change your file to .tsx and add import React from 'react' to see if it works

A component instanciation with the JSX syntax won't work in a .ts file so rename it to routes.tsx
